# ionic3 play audio with URL

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, html5-audio

I want to play external audio with Native Audio or ionic-native-media. I try for a week but I can not do it. Can someone help me please?!

here is an example:

```
import { NativeAudio } from '@ionic-native/native-audio';
this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('uniqueId1', fileurl).then(() => this.etat = "succès", () => this.etat = "erreur");
this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1', () => this.etat = "Lu avec succès");*/
```

When i display the fileurl, the url adress is good, but it didn't work!

Here is another example:

```
import { Media, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media';
this.audio = this.media.create(fileurl);
this.audio.play();
this.audio.setVolume(0.8);
```

Comment: Is there any output in the console/logcat?

Comment: Another exemple with ionic-native-media:
import { Media, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media';

this.audio = this.media.create(fileurl);
    this.audio.play();
    this.audio.setVolume(0.8);

Comment: Please dont post additional info as a comment. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48948628/edit) the question instead to include the additional example (already did that for you).

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer no i haven't output in the console/logcat because i use bluestack or noxplayer to test generated apk.